# How to export a map to a single page pdf?

Tags: export, qgis-2, pdf, print-composer

I want to export my 900 x 800 mm map to a PDF file and all I'm getting is a file with 31 page of parts of my map. How do I create a single page - whole map pdf?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Please remember that we can't see your screen, so you'll need to describe your situation to us, in some detail. For example, you've tagged this with composer, so we can guess that this is something to do with QGIS, but we don't know what version. We don't know what options you've selected. We don't really know much at all. The good news is that you can click edit below your question to update it with much more detail so we can give you a directly applicable answer.

Comment: Please have a look at this post on tips on how to improve your question: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question

Answer (score 0):

This answer was originally posted by asker.

```
It's QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour. I've played with it a little and figured it out. If anyone will 
run into the same problem, the solution is to unselect "generate atlas" in Atlas 
generation options in composer.
```